# Display Data in Fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I'm trying to display data from SQLite and display it in the listview in fragment.This is my code and when I run it, it closes automatically. This code is inside my main activity

```
    public static class ListDoctorFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView list;
    DataDB data = new DataDB();

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

    public ListDoctorFragment() {
    }
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listdoctor, container, false);

            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                names = data.getDoctorlistDB(getActivity());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, names);

            // set the adapter
            list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your 'ListView list' is not initialized. It must be something like:

```
list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
```